# OrgLimits.getAll() works only with Anonymous apex and gives exception when used in any other context

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, limitexception

I have a simple command on Orglimit which runs fine if run in anonymous as below

```
system.debug(OrgLimits.getAll());

20:25:55:076 USER_DEBUG [2]|DEBUG|(OrgLimit:[delegate=apex.sfdc.orglimits.OrgLimit@73fd0a02], OrgLimit:[delegate=apex.sfdc.orglimits.OrgLimit@4c25e223], OrgLimit:[delegate=apex.sfdc.orglimits.OrgLimit@d463654], OrgLimit:[delegate=apex.sfdc.orglimits.OrgLimit@712e48cb], OrgLimit:[delegate=apex.sfdc.orglimits.OrgLimit@5f1847d7], OrgLimit:[delegate=apex.sfdc.orglimits.OrgLimit@276937d], OrgLimit:[delegate=apex.sfdc.orglimits.OrgLimit@7db49ca4], OrgLimit:[delegate=apex.sfdc.orglimits.OrgLimit@25c01521], OrgLimit:[delegate=apex.sfdc.or
```

All fine in anonymous apex, now when i run this in regular apex class for use in my lwc page

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<System.OrgLimit> getOrglimits() {
    return OrgLimits.getAll();
}
```

I get a exception saying insufficient privileges even when i am system admin. Is there something i am doing wrong? why is the same code working in anonymous apex but not in regular apex class. How should we use Orglimit() method in apex.

```
System.NoAccessException: Insufficient Privileges: You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator
```

Comment: If I had to hazard an educated guess, it's because Lightning Session IDs do not have API access, and this is effectively an API call. I don't see anything in the docs, though. Have you tried contacting support?

Comment: but @sfdcfox the documentation points to code samples that are mostly apex and are listed in apex section of the developer guide, do you think the samples they provided are wrong? and listing them in apex section in the guide is not correct? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_OrgLimit.htm

Comment: I was guessing i am doing a silly mistake and my mistake may not be worth a salesforce case..but looking at your comment looks like it is...let me give it a try too

Comment: Its actually working from LWC component.

Comment: @salesforce-sas - does it work for u? I am using this in a LWC comp as well and i am getting this error, can you pls source your working code if its working

Comment: @AnilShivaraj Apex runs in many contexts, but some library calls have limits on when/how they can be used. The examples are perfectly valid, it's just that there may be contexts that do not allow this level of access.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot return `List<System.OrgLimit>` directly to LWC as you dont have native javascript methods like `getLimit()` and `getName()`. You need to fetch them and return to LWC component:

Apex:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<Map<String, Integer>> getOrglimitsMod() {
    List<System.OrgLimit> limits = OrgLimits.getAll();
    List<Map<String, Integer>> orgLimits = new List<Map<String, Integer>>();
    for (System.OrgLimit aLimit: limits) {
        System.debug('Limit: ' + aLimit.getName());
        System.debug('Max Limit is: ' + aLimit.getLimit());
        orgLimits.add(new Map<String,Integer>{aLimit.getName()=>aLimit.getLimit()});
    }
    return orgLimits;
}
```

LWC JS:

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api, track } from 'lwc';
import getOrglimitsMod from '@salesforce/apex/poc.getOrglimitsMod';

export default class Poc extends LightningElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        getOrglimitsMod()
            .then((res) => {
                console.log('res=>', res);
                res.map((element) => console.log(element));
            })
            .catch((err) => console.error('ERROR=>', err));
    }
}
```

OUTPUT (in chrome log):

[image]

Comment: thanks for the sample you gave, i am very confused with the behaviour because i am running the exact same code you have and i still get an error in my chrome log as below (i am not able to attach screenshot because of stackexchange limitation)

Comment: originalTarget:
body: {exceptionType: "System.NoAccessException", isUserDefinedException: false, message: "Insufficient Privileges: You do not have the level…ord or your administrator if access is necessary.", stackTrace: "Class.System.OrgLimits.getAll: line 5, column 1↵Cl…ScratchOrgDetails.getOrglimits: line 29, column 1"}
ok: false
status: 400
statusText: "Bad Request"
__proto__: Object

Comment: how is your code working with a LWC context but its consistently failing when i try, can you provide the meta file of the LWC - i am guessing is this some API version issue?

Comment: exceptionType: "System.NoAccessException"
isUserDefinedException: false
message: "Insufficient Privileges: You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary."
stackTrace: "Class.System.OrgLimits.getAll: line 5, column 1↵Class.ScratchOrgDetails.getOrglimits: line 29, column 1"                                            (It exactly fails where the line Orglimits is executed in apex)

Comment: what is the api version of apex class?

Comment: I am currently using api version 46, what is the version that you have used?                                                        
 <ApexClass xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>46.0</apiVersion>
    <status>Active</status>
</ApexClass>

Comment: also i see the apex class works when i use it in VF context

Comment: I think i understand now how @salesforce-sas example worked, the apex executes properly when run on a record page context. I tried to execute the LWC with same code in a record page context and it works but gives Insufficient privilege exception when you put the LWC in home page and run in home page context. Thats why your example worked, pls try to use the same component in a home page and you will get the error i am seeing

Comment: I was actually executing it using `isUrlAddressable` interface in aura component.